# Call singularity exec from a shell script in R

Tags: r, bash, shell, singularity-container

I have a bash script where I use **singularity exec** to run a program from inside the container. I want to call this script in R using the **system()** function. Everything works fine until it reaches the line containing **singularity exec**, where I get the error : **"./script.sh: line 22: singularity: command not found "**

The bash script works well when I call it directly in command line.

How could I make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it that the error message is not _command not found_, but something like _bash: singularity: command not found_?

Comment: @user1934428 It's  "./script.sh: line 22: singularity: command not found"

Comment: Then you obviously have to fix your [PATH](https://linuxconfig.org/linux-path-environment-variable)....